# How to run pyspark on EC2 with IPython starting from the spark-ec2 launch process?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

Three steps and I have a spark context in my IPython notebook:

1.) Launch spark on EC2 using the [these instructions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html).
2.) Install [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/) on every node (set PATH accordingly).
3.) Login to master, `cd` to the spark folder, then run:

```
MASTER=spark://<public DNS>:7077 PYSPARK_PYTHON=~/anaconda2/bin/python PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook  --ip="*"' ./bin/pyspark
```

This process makes the IPython notebook available on < master public DNS >:8888, which is great, but ... I am currently using a [csshx](http://code.google.com/p/csshx/) style solution to accomplish step 2.

Question:

- **How can I set install requirements (on AWS or elsewhere) so that the `spark-ec2` script spins up machines with the desired setup?**
- If that's not possible or simply clunky, what would you suggest? *(command line only solutions are preferred)*